# Generating random images from specific folders

Tags: java, swing

For a game, I want to create a mechanism where 9 different random numbers are generated within a certain range and 9 corresponding pictures appear on the screen in three different columns as a result. But how do I ensure that the folder referred to for each column of images is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Map where the key is the random number, and the value is the folder.

Comment: whats a map? Excuse my ignorance, Im new to java

Comment: An Interface whose instances (like HashMap) let you associate a key with a value. In your case, the key would be the random number, and the value the folder. Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: is there anyother way to do it?

Comment: Yes, but I think the best solution on this case is a Map.

Comment: Im on a bit of a time crunch. I was wondering if there were other solutions, using some more basic concepts. Again, I apologize for my stupidity

Comment: Maybe you could achieve similar results with two paralell arrays